# Read text file from smart card with pkcs#11

Tags: c++, security, smartcard, pkcs#11

I have a blank smart card `(SLE66CX322P, Cardos 4.3b)` and a card reader/writer (`Gemalto CT 40)`. Using a software I can initialize the card, generate keys, certificates etc. I also can create a simple `ASCII` file with some text which will be stored on the smart card. My qustion is, how can I read out the content of this ASCII file in `C/C++` using the `pkcs#11 API`?

Here comes what I have tried so far (using also Qt):

---------- **cardreader.h** ------------

```
#ifndef CARDREADER_H
#define CARDREADER_H

#include "cm-pkcs11.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtDebug>

class CardReader: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:

    CK_RV rv;
    CK_ULONG slotCount;
    CK_SLOT_ID slotIds[10];
    CK_SLOT_ID slotId;
    CK_SESSION_HANDLE session;
    CK_TOKEN_INFO_PTR info;

    void readCard();

public:

    explicit CardReader(QObject *parent = 0);
};

#endif // CARDREADER_H
```

------- **cardreader.cpp** ----------

```
#include "cardreader.h"

CardReader::CardReader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    readCard();
}

/***********************************************************************/

void CardReader::readCard()
{
    rv = C_Initialize(NULL_PTR);

    slotCount = 10;
    rv = C_GetSlotList(CK_TRUE, slotIds, &slotCount);
    qWarning() << "Found" << slotCount << "slots";

    if (rv != CKR_OK || slotCount < 1)
    {
        qWarning() << "No slots found -> exit";
        return;
    }

    slotId = slotIds[0];

    rv = C_OpenSession(slotId, CKF_SERIAL_SESSION|CKF_RW_SESSION, NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR, &session);

    if (rv != CKR_OK)
    {
        qWarning() << "Sessions could not be opened -> exit";
        qWarning() << "RV (as hex value) = " << QString("%1").arg(rv, 0, 16);
        return;
    }

    /*********************************************************************/

    CK_OBJECT_CLASS dataClass = CKO_DATA;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE handleObject;
    CK_UTF8CHAR label[] = {"MyLabel"};
    CK_ULONG ulCount = 4ul;
    CK_CHAR application[] = {"TestApplication"};
    CK_BYTE dataValue[] = {"MyData"};
    CK_BBOOL valid = CK_TRUE;
    CK_ATTRIBUTE dataTemp[] =
    {
        {CKA_CLASS, &dataClass, sizeof(dataClass)},
        {CKA_VALUE, dataValue, sizeof(dataValue)},
        {CKA_LABEL, label, sizeof(label)-1},
        //{CKA_APPLICATION, application, sizeof(application)}
        {CKA_TOKEN, &valid, sizeof(true)}
    };

    rv = C_FindObjectsInit(session, dataTemp, 0);
    if (rv != CKR_OK)
    {
        qWarning() << "C_FindObjectsInit Error -> exit";
        qWarning() << "C_FindObjectsInit Error" << QString("%1").arg(rv, 0, 16);
        return;
    }


    while (1)
    {
        rv = C_FindObjects(session, &handleObject, 1, &ulCount);
        qWarning() << "C_FindObjects Result =" << QString("%1").arg(rv, 0, 16) << ", count =" << ulCount;
        if (rv != CKR_OK || ulCount == 0)
            break;

        rv = C_GetAttributeValue(session, handleObject, dataTemp, ulCount);

        if (rv != CKR_OK)
        {
            qWarning() << "C_GetAttributeValue error -> exit";
            qWarning() << "RV (as hex value) = " << QString("%1").arg(rv, 0, 16) << ", count = " << ulCount;
            return;
        }

        qWarning() << (const char *) dataTemp[0].pValue;
        qWarning() << (const char *) dataTemp[1].pValue;
        qWarning() << (const char *) dataTemp[2].pValue;
        qWarning() << (const char *) dataTemp[3].pValue;
    }
}
```

---------- **main.cpp** ----------

```
#include "cardreader.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    CardReader c;

    return a.exec();
}
```

The result is that the block

```
        qWarning() << (const char *) dataTemp[0].pValue;
        qWarning() << (const char *) dataTemp[1].pValue;
        qWarning() << (const char *) dataTemp[2].pValue;
        qWarning() << (const char *) dataTemp[3].pValue;
```

is printed four times in the console but always with `MyLabel` and `MyData` as result which I have specified at the beginning of `CardReader::readCard()`. The content of the text file on the smart card is different of course, but is not shown in the output unfortunately.

I'd like also to mention that I was also able to use the `C_CreateObject()` function. This generated a second ASCII file on the smart card. But this second file I could not read out either with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause:

- Your `ulCount` variable gets overwritten by `C_FindObjects()` to `1`.
- You need to re-assign it to `4` again before calling the `C_GetAttributeValue`.
- This way your code reads only the first attribute in the template.

---

Some additional (random) notes:

- As you do not call `C_Login()`, you can view/access only public objects (objects with set CKA_PRIVATE are hidden for you).
- Zero `ulCount` argument for `C_FindObjectsInit()` causes that your code enumerates all token objects -- you probably wanted the `CKA_CLASS` and `CKA_LABEL` filter to be effective.
- I would recommend not to use the same template for `C_FindObjectsInit()` and `C_GetAttributeValue()`
- Your `dataValue` buffer is quite small -- are you sure that the value will fit?

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, your tips solved it. I've reassigned ```4``` to ```ulCount```, changed the last argument of ```C_FindObjectsInit()``` to 1 and increased the buffer of ```dataValue``` and ```label```. But, I'm not sure what the ```CK_ULONG``` value in ```C_FindObjectsInit()``` does. When I enter ```2``` I get no results. With ```1``` I get the content of my chip card. ```0``` gives me a lot more results with non-readable characters. I thought the ```CK_ULONG``` value tells me how many attributes of the text file has to fit to the template, and two attr. do fit: ```dataValue``` and ```label```.

Comment: @Varius the `CK_ULONG ulCount` parameter of `C_FindObjectsInit()` defines how many attributes (and their values) are matched in the search template. In your case 0="all objects", 1="objects with CKA_CLASS==CKO_DATA" and 2="objects with CKA_CLASS==CKO_DATA and CKA_VALUE==MyData". As your data objects probably do not contain "MyData" your search gives you no results for `ulCount=2`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Additionally, you should not treat attribute values (`pValue`) as zero terminated strings. You should use the `valueLen` field to determine output length and dump only valid bytes.

Comment: And you should reset all the fields `valueLen` in the template before calling `C_GetAttributeValue()`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This makes sense now. Indeed, I didn't have any file with ```MyData``` on the card. So ```ulCount=1``` gave me all files of the type ```CKO_DATA``` independent of their ```CKA_VALUE```. And ```ulCount=2``` would give me all files of type ```CKO_DATA``` and a value of "MyData" (if I had such a file on the card...). Got it now. Thanks